# Couldn't connect to a MySQL DB via JWS app

Tags: java, mysql, database, java-web-start

Could someone help me with establishing connection with my DB on non-localhost server?

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+SERVER+"/javadb?user=javadb&password=*****");
```

How could I set-up the SERVER String for my domain www.lmntstudio.cz?
All required files are stored in one folder on the server.

I did it first on my localhost server and everything works well. But with the connection to another server is trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not to open MySQL connection from the client/user machine to the server. Because this would make your DB server open and prone to attacks.

Rather consider using web service. call that web service from your JWS application from client side and get the data.

Another point to consider is that opening a connection on a port say 3360 may be blocked by the firewall. If my firewall is set to block any out bound connection on port 3306 the connection could not be established.

Comment: Hm, interesting. This could be the problem. But I don't quite understand what you mean by connecting from client side (or how you said).

Comment: A Java Web Start application first gets downloaded to the client/user machine and from there it run as a local application. So when your are creating the DB connection, it will connect from the users machine to the server.

Comment: This app is Instant Messenger and this connection is opening only on server side and only I have access to server side. But the firewall on the host server could be causing this trouble.

Comment: So if I establish connection from my local machine then this app would work properly... So i try it and get feedback. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This answer was useful even I couldn't resolve the problem 'cause the app tells me "Access denied" so there must be a firewall or other protection :)

Comment: "Access denied" this may be due to the reason that your mysql server is not configured to accept connection from other system. Say if your server is running on 192.168.10.1 then you need to configure it to accept connection from other system like 192.168.10.2. By default it is open to connection from local host. You can configure your mysql server through MySQL query browser UI and MySQL Administrator UI

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure the MySQL is running in default port 3306 else you need change the port number accordingly.

```
     Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(  
                   "jdbc:mysql://www.lmntstudio.cz:3306/javadb", "username", "password");
```

instead of www.lmntstudio.cz you can use ip of the domain.

run the following in the command line to get the ip

```
          cmd prompt> nslookup www.lmntstudio.cz
```

The Url syntax as follows

```
       jdbc:mysql://(host/ip):port/databasename", "username", "password"
```

Comment: This solution could be possible but I use my host server so I don't have access to try this command. But I think I understand. I tried a lot of addresses: my host, localhost, MySQL server with/without port, etc. There must be another problem, so I thank you for this answer.

Comment: If you hosted in data center then they will provide you c-panel access and phpmyadmin account. if you not received please ask them then only you can login to database server.